# Delayed successful SSL connection with node.js server and esp8266 client

Tags: node.js, ssl, esp8266

i am using a node.js server to communicate with my ESP8266 client using SSL but the connection is not stable and it takes 8 to 9 tries sometimes and sometimes 20-25 tries to connect to the server the number of tries are not fixed at all. the SSL certificate uses a 2048 bit key. Using the library websocket

```
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
WebSocketsClient webSocket;
WebSocket.beginSSL("hostname.com",port,"/socket.io/transport=websocket","fingerprint");
```

Comment: can you show some code please and how you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: Impossible to answer without looking at the handshake. As a rule of thumb, always use ECC. E.g., use ECDSA certs on curves like NIST P-256 and use a ECDHE key exchange with reasonable parameters regarding curve and hash function. RSA is memory-intensive. If you have say 2048 bit keys each in a 3-part certificate chain, verification with such keylengths will already cost more memory than what's available on the ESP8266.

Comment: but it connects after sometime so how can i be sure that the data after it connects is encrypted or not.. and i cnt use ECDSA because of the drawbacks of its key is there a way i can use this only

Comment: You would have to analyze the handshake using Wireshark on your router or something. Then you can at least see where the handshake stops or on what parameters it runs. You'd also have to hook into your ESP libs to see where the handshake goes wrong. After all, it should only take one try to connect and do the handshake successfully, not 8 to 25..

Comment: if it connects over https/wss, the encryption is working.